# python discord bot- just can't get it online (just a simple question)

Tags: python, server, discord, bots

I was trying to make my bot go online but it never worked I just used these 3 lines of code:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
client.run('token')
```

Comment: How did it not work? What error did it return? Are you using an actual token, or just that `'token'` string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: [Creating a Discord Connection](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#creating-a-discord-connection)

It looks like you need to load environment variables with the `os.getenv()` function

You have to create a connection to discord

```py
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

> Here, you’ve created a Client and implemented its on_ready() event handler, which handles the event when the Client has established a connection to Discord and it has finished preparing the data that Discord has sent, such as login state, guild and channel data, and more.